# Why aren't the values of the dropdowns bound?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

[Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) is a great library to implement MVVM.

The following minimal sample binds a grid using `knockout.js`.

**View**

```
<div id="divDecision">
  <div id="divDecisionBinding" data-bind="template: { name: 'tmplDecision' }">/div>
  <script id="tmplDecision" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <table id="tblDecision">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Candidate</th>
          <th>Decision</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach:decisionList" id="tbList">
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: candidate"></td>
          <td>
            <select data-bind="attr: { id: 'cmbDecision' + ':' + $index(), name: 'cmbDecision' + ':' + $index()}, options: viewModelDecision.decisionLookup, value: 'decision', optionsText: 'decision_desc', optionsCaption: 'Please select'"></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
</div>
```

**viewModelDecision** (2 members: decisionLookup and decisionList)

```
decisionLookup
0 : {decision: "N", decision_desc: "No need"}
1 : {decision: "A", decision_desc: "Approved"}
2 : {decision: "R", decision_desc: "Rejected"}
decisionList
0 : {candidate: "000000001", decision: "A" }
1 : {candidate: "000000002", decision: "N" }
```

**Script**

```
var viewModelDecision;
//viewModelDecision gets loaded from a web service
viewModelDecision = result;
//Now the binding happens
ko.applyBindings(viewModelDecision, document.getElementById("divDecision"));
```

**Output**

```
000000001 Please select
000000002 Please select
```

**Findings**

1. The field `candidate` is successfully bound
2. The options of the dropdownlist `cmbDecision:X` are successfully bound
3. The values of the dropdownlist `cmbDecision:X` are not bound - the
   caption "`Please select`" is selected by default.

**Question**

Why aren't the values of the dropdown list selected by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` binding should be targeting an observable property of your viewmodel.

You probably meant to use the `optionsValue` binding to tell knockout to use the ids stored in `.decision` as a selection.

```
<select data-bind="options: viewModelDecision.decisionLookup, value: selectedDecision, optionsValue: 'decision', optionsText: 'decision_desc', optionsCaption: 'Please select'"></select>
```

And in your vm:

```
this.selectedDecision = ko.observable("A"); // Pre-select the 2nd item
```

Comment: I partly understand what you're saying. However, my viewModelDecision is coming from a web service - (viewModelDecision = result). I will update the question to make this more clear. How do I then set selectedDecision in the VM?

Comment: Your answer worked with the addtion of optionsValue and the correction of value: 'decision' to a variable. I was not able to understand the observable part. It would be useful if you could also explain how to set this.selectedDecision.

Comment: You set an observable by calling it with a new value. The value needs to correspond to one of the decision props in your list for your select to correctly update. E.g.: this.selectedDecision(decisionLookup[0].decision) to select the first one. Note that you don't need the optionsValue binding; you can also store actual references to the objects instead of just one property.